# ACROSS or IN? "They have been to six countries across three continents." OR "They have been to six countries across three continents."

Tags: grammar, meaning, prepositions, idiomatic-language

This sentence is from the BBC[genetic disease that results in blindness](https://www.bbc.com/news/av/world-62960970) It tells about a genetic disease that make sufferers go blind over time. So, they travel around the world before they go blind.

**So far, they have been to six countries across three continents.**

I wonder why is it **"...across three continents"** but not **"...in three continents."**

Comment: Is your subject line right? "They have been six countries across three continents"?

Comment: It's just a stylistic choice. _Across_ suggests the idea of the six countries in question being spread over a wide area (not just the countries nearest to where the people live).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Six countries **in** three continents*" could perhaps sound like there were 6 *in each* of the 3, or at least leave room for that ambiguity.

"*Six countries **across** three continents*" means that the six countries were *spread across* three continents, which is what I perceive is the intended meaning.